# TensorFlow: Is there a way to measure FLOPS for a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The closest example I can get is found in this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/899

With this minimum reproducible code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.python.framework.ops as ops 
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
  A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [25,16] ))
  B = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [16,9] ))
  C = tf.matmul(A,B) # shape=[25,9]
for op in g.get_operations():
  flops = ops.get_stats_for_node_def(g, op.node_def, 'flops').value
  if flops is not None:
    print 'Flops should be ~',2*25*16*9
    print '25 x 25 x 9 would be',2*25*25*9 # ignores internal dim, repeats first
    print 'TF stats gives',flops
```

However, the FLOPS returned is always None. Is there a way to concretely measure FLOPS, especially with a PB file?

Comment: Any clue on how to do it on TF 2.0?

Comment: you can use model_profiler in TF2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A little bit late but maybe it helps some visitors in future. For your example I successfully tested the following snippet:

```
g = tf.Graph()
run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
with g.as_default():
    A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [25,16] ))
    B = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [16,9] ))
    C = tf.matmul(A,B) # shape=[25,9]

    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()    
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(g, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
    if flops is not None:
        print('Flops should be ~',2*25*16*9)
        print('25 x 25 x 9 would be',2*25*25*9) # ignores internal dim, repeats first
        print('TF stats gives',flops.total_float_ops)
```

It's also possible to use the profiler in combination with `Keras` like the following snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet

run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    K.set_session(sess)
    net = MobileNet(alpha=.75, input_tensor=tf.placeholder('float32', shape=(1,32,32,3)))

    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()    
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(sess.graph, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.trainable_variables_parameter()    
    params = tf.profiler.profile(sess.graph, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

    print("{:,} --- {:,}".format(flops.total_float_ops, params.total_parameters))
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: The first snippet outputs `Flops should be ~ 7200` and `TF stats gives 8288`. Why this difference? I build on this answer to explain it.

Comment: It works like a charm. But is there any way to prevent `tf.profiler.profile` from logging to console?

Answer (score 29):

I would like to build on Tobias Schnek's answer as well as answering the original question: how to get FLOP from a `pb` file.

Running the first snippet of code from Tobias answer with TensorFlow 1.6.0

```
g = tf.Graph()
run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
with g.as_default():
    A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([25,16]))
    B = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16,9]))
    C = tf.matmul(A,B)

    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()    
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(g, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
    if flops is not None:
        print('Flops should be ~',2*25*16*9)
        print('TF stats gives',flops.total_float_ops)
```

We get the following ouput:

```
Flops should be ~ 7200
TF stats gives 8288
```

So, why do we get `8288` instead of the *expected* result `7200=2*25*16*9`<sup>[a]</sup>? The answer is in the way the tensors `A` and `B` are initialised. Initialising with a Gaussian distribution costs some FLOP. Changing the definition of `A` and `B` by

```
    A = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros([25, 16]))
    B = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros([16, 9]))
```

gives the expected output `7200`.

Usually, a network's variables are initialised with Gaussian distributions among other schemes. Most of the time, we are not interested by the initialisation FLOP as they are done once during initialisation and do not happen during the training nor the inference. So, **how could one get the exact number of FLOP disregarding the initialisation FLOP**?

**Freeze the graph** with a `pb`. Calculating the FLOP from a `pb` file was, actually, the OP's use case.

The following snippet illustrates this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

def load_pb(pb):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(pb, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph

# ***** (1) Create Graph *****
g = tf.Graph()
sess = tf.Session(graph=g)
with g.as_default():
    A = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_normal([25, 16]))
    B = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random_normal([16, 9]))
    C = tf.matmul(A, B, name='output')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(g, options = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation())
    print('FLOP before freezing', flops.total_float_ops)
# *****************************        

# ***** (2) freeze graph *****
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, g.as_graph_def(), ['output'])

with tf.gfile.GFile('graph.pb', "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
# *****************************


# ***** (3) Load frozen graph *****
g2 = load_pb('./graph.pb')
with g2.as_default():
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(g2, options = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation())
    print('FLOP after freezing', flops.total_float_ops)
```

outputs

```
FLOP before freezing 8288
FLOP after freezing 7200
```

---

<sup>[a]</sup> Usually the FLOP of a matrix multiplication are mq(2p -1) for the product AB where `A[m, p]` and `B[p, q]` but TensorFlow returns 2mpq for some reason. An [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19746) has been opened to understand why.

Comment: Freezing the graph works indeed !! Thank you for the answer !!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed information! I have one more problem to the solution above: I received frozen graphs (.pb) with 2-dimensional input tensors, where the shape is not fully defined (e.g. [?,3]), so your code gives me ```FLOP after freezing 0
12 ops no flops stats due to incomplete shapes.``` Is there a way to just "assume" a certain shape without re-doing the training process?

Answer (score 5):

The above approaches no longer work for TF2.0 as the profiler methods have been deprecated and moved under `compat.v1`. Seems like this feature still needs to be implemented.

Below is an issue on Github:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809

Comment: What's about this version? https://gist.github.com/scheckmedia/cadc5eb3d74ed57a4f3d78011a9f6f7c

Answer (score 3):

[Another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13245719/talha-ilyas) posted an answer. It was deleted by a mod so it cannot be restored. But it does solve the problem, and better than other answers. So I repeat it here.

---

You can use following pip package to get some basic information like model's memory requirement, no. of parameters, flops etc.

https://pypi.org/project/model-profiler

it'll output something like

| Model Profile | Value | Unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selected GPUs | ['0', '1'] | GPU IDs |
| No. of FLOPs | 0.30932349055999997 | BFLOPs |
| GPU Memory Requirement | 7.4066760912537575 | GB |
| Model Parameters | 138.357544 | Million |
| Memory Required by Model Weights | 527.7921447753906 | MB |

---

### Usage

[Copied verbatim from the library website]

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16

model = VGG16(include_top=True)

from model_profiler import model_profiler

Batch_size = 128
profile = model_profiler(model, Batch_size)

print(profile)
```

Comment: Note: From looking at the source, it seems this library does not implement all common layers. So the output may be quite wrong. As it is still young, the author may fix this in the future.