# Measuring Flops for TFLite Model in Tensorflow 2.X

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to measure FLOPS for a TFLite model in TF2.
I know that Tensorflow 1.x had the tf.profiler, which was awesome for measuring flops. It doesn't seem to work well with tf.keras.

Could anybody please describe how to measure FLOPs for a TFLite model in TF2? I can't seem to find an answer online.
Thank you all so much for your time.

Edit: The link commented below does not help with tflite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow: Is there a way to measure FLOPS for a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085938/tensorflow-is-there-a-way-to-measure-flops-for-a-model)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this works for TFLite. Do you know of any other way? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and wrote a simple python package to roughly calculate FLOPS.

https://github.com/lisosia/tflite-flops

Only Conv and DepthwiseConv layers are considered, but it was sufficient for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way you can calculate the FLOPS for a tflite model. However, you can estimate its value indirectly, by following these 3 steps:

1. Use the official [TFLite performance tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement) to measure how long your model takes (in ms) to perform a single inference.
2. Use some benchmark app (such as [xOPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcom.saplin.xOPS&hl=en&gl=US)) to estimate how many floating-point operations per second (FLOPS) your target device can run.
3. Use the results you got from steps 1 and 2 to estimate the number of floating-point operations your model performs during a single inference.

The final result will probably be a rough approximation, but it still can bring some value to your performance analysis.