# Counting FLOPS in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, flops

Is there a way to count FLOPS for the training and prediction of tensorflow models?
The models are running on a CPU using tensorflow 2.8.0 and i would not like to use an external (e.g. command line) tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow: Is there a way to measure FLOPS for a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085938/tensorflow-is-there-a-way-to-measure-flops-for-a-model)

Comment: @Innat I don't know, does it?

Comment: Please try something before you post something. Thanks.

Comment: @Innat Ok i will you don't have to beg me.